# Swift 4 - Push a ViewController from a UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm stuck in my project and is in need for some help. I want to push/present a `UICollectionViewController` from a `UICollectionViewCell` **including** my `UINavigationBar`. I have understand that you can not actually present a ViewController from a Cell? How do I supposed to do in this case? My problem is that my NavigationBar won´t show up.

Here is my Cell:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

lazy var followersLabelButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("followers", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followers), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc fileprivate func followers() {

    let newController = NewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

   }
```

And the CollectionViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var userId: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        collectionView?.register(UserProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader

        header.user = self.user

        return header
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)


    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- Inside the cell

```
weak var delegate:UserProfileController?
```

2- Inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.delegate = self
```

3- Use this inside the cell

```
delegate?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

BTW i think you mean

```
delegate?.navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a new ViewController you should create a new delegate in your Cell like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol CellDelegate {
    func presentViewController()
}    

class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var delegate: CellDelegate?

    lazy var followersLabelButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("followers", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followers), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func followers() {
        delegate.presentViewController
    }

}
```

While in your ViewController you should make the delegate function works like this

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
 , CellDelegate {

    var userId: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(UserProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader

        header.user = self.user

        // Remember to set the delegate for the cell
        header.delegate = self

        return header
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }

    func presentViewController() {
        let newController = NewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use a comment rather than an answer if you need clarification before being able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

it`s not right way do this in view. Use MVC way:
Move

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followers), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to UserProfileController in method

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader as! UserProfileHeader
        header.followersLabelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followers), for: .touchUpInside)
        header.user = self.user

        return header
    }
```

and rewrite

```
@objc func followers() {

    let newController = self.navigationController

    newController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think you shouldn't be presenting from the cell at all, even if you have a reference to the viewController. I'd rather call a function on the delegate, and leave it to decide what to do -

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol UserProfileHeaderDelegate: class {
    func followersTapped()
}


class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var headerDelegate: UserProfileHeaderDelegate?

    lazy var followersLabelButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("followers", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followers), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc fileprivate func followers() {
        self.headerDelegate?.followersTapped()
    }
}
```

In the viewController -

```
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UserProfileHeaderDelegate {

    // etc, etc......

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader

        header.user = self.user

        // Remember to set the delegate for the cell
        header.headerDelegate = self

        return header
    }


    // Implement the UserProfileHeaderDelegate protocol - this is called from within the cell
    // so all the cell knows is that its delegate implements this protocol, which has the followersTapped() function

    func followersTapped() {
        let newController = NewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This way your viewController is not concerned with the inner workings of your cell, and vice-versa.

Comment: Didn´t get it to work. But my project is currently only a test. But I will check it out more later. Thanks!